# Рушится разметка при :hover c псевдо-элементом ::before

Tags: html, css, hover

Начал изучать HTML/CSS, c заделом на будущее, с применением БЭМ-технологии.

```css
.main {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #e3e3e1;
}
.main__title {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #999999;
    color: #fff;
}
.main__license {
    color: #73687f;
    position: relative;
}
.main__license--borderBottom {
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d1;
}
.main__license--borderBottom:hover::before {
    content: '✔ ';
    color: #8d87a0;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="main__title">TITLE</div>
    <div class="main__license">
        <div class="main__license main__license--borderBottom"><span class="main__license--checkBox">
            </span>LICENSES</div>
        <div class="main__license main__license--borderBottom">Element_1</div>
        <div class="main__license main__license--borderBottom">Element_2</div>
        <div class="main__license main__license--borderBottom">Element_3</div>
        <div class="main__license main__license--borderBottom">Element_4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Задумка состоит в следующем, - при наведении мышки на элемент, будет отображается символ "✔" перед текстом.

Но почему-то при наведении съезжает разметка самого элемента на один пиксель вниз, это можно удивить по *border-bottom*.

Не совсем очевидный момент на текущим момент, в чем кроется причина подобного поведения.

**Вопрос**:
В чем причина увеличения размера блока элемента при hover c свойством *content: ""*?

Comment: это в произвольном месте должно быть ? или же в определённых местах галочка должна появляться ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рушится из-за line-height 
http://htmlbook.ru/css/line-height

Решение: добавить для `.main__license--borderBottom:hover::before` - `line-height: 1`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.main {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #e3e3e1;
}
.main__title {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #999999;
  color: #fff;
}
.main__license {
  color: #73687f;
  position: relative;
}
.main__license--borderBottom {
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d1;
}
.main__license--borderBottom:hover::before {
  content: '✔ ';
  line-height: 1;
  color: #8d87a0;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="main__title">TITLE</div>
    <div class="main__license">
        <div class="main__license main__license--borderBottom">
            <span class="main__license--checkBox"></span>LICENSES
        </div>
        <div class="main__license main__license--borderBottom">Element_1</div>
        <div class="main__license main__license--borderBottom">Element_2</div>
        <div class="main__license main__license--borderBottom">Element_3</div>
        <div class="main__license main__license--borderBottom">Element_4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wm2dvgya/)

Comment: Супер. Большое спасибо за решение проблемы.